# Socket.io and Nodejs tutorials

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good beginners tutorial to socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094350/good-beginners-tutorial-to-socket-io)

Hello,

there are not many information on www.socket.io, I would study how it works.

Could you advice me some tutorials for socket.io and nodejs ?

thank you

Comment: This appears to be similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094350/good-beginners-tutorial-to-socket-io).

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnode.js%5D+tutorials