# Having trouble with the Socket.IO Tutorial samples. Incomplete documentation or PEBCAK?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Over the weekend, I was trying to figure out websockets (since I think it would probably be a really fun thing to know).

I did a search around for socket.io tutorials and found this [Good beginners tutorial to socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094350/good-beginners-tutorial-to-socket-io) which suggested I start on http://socket.io

On a fresh ubuntu I built node.js  `4.1.13-pre` (many packages won't work with the current 0.5.8)

I added, NPM and the express, jade & socket.io packages.

I set up and ran a server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8000);  // I moved the port
var express = require('express');  // I had to add this
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

I cloned `https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io.git` and made an `index.html` in the directory above the place I cloned socket IO into

```
 <script src="socket.io/lib/socket.io.js"></script> <!-- changed path from example -->
 <script>
   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');
   socket.on('news', function (data) {
     console.log(data);
     socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
   });
 </script>
```

When I load up the index page locally, I get the error:  `require not defined`

I'm assuming that I've missed something here,  is the client-side JS not the same one from the lib folder?  DO I need to add something to allow for the existence of 'require'?

What am I missing? How do I serve up the client side JS correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` instead.

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that the reason I switched from the "documentation-provided" code was because that didn't work either. What I *didn't* try is `"http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"` maybe socket.io 'compiles' and server the client-code and adds its own url-transport  to express.

Comment: Yes, Socket.IO takes care of serving the client code. But `/socket.io/socket.io.js` should be equivalent to `http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js` (assuming you are serving the HTML file from `http://localhost:8000`).

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something simple.  I'm definitely going to want to communication / socket server to be separate from the static files. So I guess I was trying to run before I could walk.  The static page was being served seperately, which complicated stuff.

Comment: Tested and verified - you actually serve the client side JS file *through* the socket itself.  So, if you're socket is on 8000 you pull the client side JS through `http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js` not the express default `3000` or whatever.