# App with the counter of clicks displayed in real time using Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

Imagine that I have an app that only shows the button and the user is able to click on this button. Below the button there is a counter of clicks. It will display a sum of all clicks from all user. The idea is similar to the cookie clicker game, but I would like to make this like a multiplayer game.

Is this possible to see this counter in real time in app ?

I was wondering if I can use here the Socket.IO.

Comment: Are you familiar with node.js and socket.io?

Comment: I know node.js but just a little unfortunately with socket.io I am not familiar at all. I would like to practise node, angular and socket at the app I have described above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know how to run a node app, here is a very **basic** example:

**File server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app=express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var server = require('socket.io')(http);
var port=89;

var counter=0;//Initial counter value 

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
    });


server.on('connection', function(socket)
{
    console.log('a user connected');

    //on user connected sends the current click count
    socket.emit('click_count',counter);

    //when user click the button
    socket.on('clicked',function(){
    counter+=1;//increments global click count

    server.emit('click_count',counter);//send to all users new counter value
    });

});

//starting server
http.listen(port, function()
{
    console.log('listening on port:'+port);
});
```

**File index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Socket.IO Clicker</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <h1 style="text-align: center">Click Counter</h1> </div>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12 ">
            <p style="text-align: center"><button id='btn_click' class="bnt btn-lg btn-success">Click Me!</button></p>

            <p style="text-align: center">Click counts:<span id="counter"></span></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    $(function () {

        var socket = io();//connect to the socket

        socket.on('connect',function()
        {
           console.log('Yeah I am connected!!');
        });

        //Listen from server.js
        socket.on('click_count',function(value)
        {
            $('#counter').html(value);//Set new count value
        });

        //Says to server that the button has been clicked
        $('#btn_click').click(function()
        {
            socket.emit('clicked');//Emitting user click
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**File package.json**

```
{
    "name": "ClickME",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Multiclick",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "4.10.2",
        "socket.io": "1.7.2"
    }
}
```

**Localhost usage**

- open prompt
- cd /files_directory/
- npm install
- node server.js

then open your browser and open multiple tabs on:

- http://127.0.0.1:89/

Enjoy :)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Could you please tell me if there is possible to compare the counters(I have made two independent counters) after every click to... for example make the name of the counter green if the value is higher than the second one.

Comment: @PawełStanecki yes sure! I suggest to use rooms or namespaces to do that...please have a look [here](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/)

Comment: Great ! Thank you for all tips!

Answer (score 0):

In node.js socket connection (server port) is shared between child processes (cluster mode: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html ). You can also scale web sockets among several machines (https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/). 
If you are going to create small app you will probably have one server (with many processes) and you can create then a simple queue which will gather all increments. Remember that TCP/IP will ensure you will get web socket requests in the order in which they have been generated. This queue will make/sync requests to your DB.
In case of many servers the app scaling will be more complicated. Then the simple app queue will be replaced with your DB (and proper isolation level) or with e.g. redis or rabbitmq.
PS. Socket.io is good choice.

Comment: Thanks you. I will probably make very small app. Do you know any good tutorial or documentation for Socket.IO ?

Comment: Official docs seem to be good (you have link in my response). Besides that look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094350/good-beginners-tutorial-to-socket-io.